# Pushing a new branch to gerrit with tracked changes

Tags: git, gerrit

Currently, i am using gerrit as a code review. Whenever i am creating a new branch i use to push it using below command:

**git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/new_branch**

But today i am having some having some local changes which i have tracked. But i am planning to push these changes along with branch. Normally, it is possible to do **git add** and then  **git commit** and push the branch but these will come with commit-id in log. But i don't want these changes to reflect in log (means without commiting i want these changes in new branch as apart of git). Is it possible? 
Have someone tried the same?

Comment: So, if I understand your question correctly, you're trying to commit changes to a branch, *without* actually committing those changes to the branch? Also, `git push origin HEAD:new_branch` should be equivalent to `git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/new_branch`.

Comment: @Cupcake, yes you are right, i want to push the new branch along with tracked changes without actually commiting them. Since, i am using gerrit syatem, thats why i opted git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/new_branch this command. Any hints of doing this??

Comment: Sorry, off the top of my head, I don't know. I would expect that you need to commit changes if you wanted to push them. Let me ask a more important question: ***why are you trying to do this?***

Comment: Actually regulary, we need to rebase our code with some open source project and at every rebase we are creating a new branch. During this rebase, we are getting enormous amount of merge conflicts. So some times, for small small changes also we need to create fixup commits and at later stage we have to squash these fixups!. So, i don't want to bear that pain. Thats my main intention. I hope i am clear to you now.

Comment: Why aren't you merging the upstream project?

Comment: @stephen We can not do so, as per some restrictions of project policies :(

Comment: That makes no sense. Do you mean making your changes available to the upstream project? I see no reason to allow `git rebase` but to disallow `git merge`.